# Run a function once on bottle.py startup

Tags: python, scheduling, bottle

I have a bottle app that I eventually wan't to deploy on apache (just fyi in case that's important). 
Now I need to run a function once after the bottle app is started. I can't just put it into a routed function because it has to run even if no user has accessed the site yet.

Any best pratice to do this ?

The function starts a APScheduler Instance and adds a jobstore to it.

Comment: [The same question for Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276078/whats-the-right-approach-for-calling-functions-after-a-flask-app-is-run)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do.

```
def initialize():
    //init whatever you need.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize()
    @bottle.run(port='8080', yatta yatta)
```

Comment: This only works if you're using the built-in server. Otherwise it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly your problem is simply a sync vs async issue.  Use gevent to easily convert to microthreads, and then launch each separately. You can even add a delay either in your function or before with `gevent.sleep` if you want to wait for the web server to finish launching.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal, spawn, joinall
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from bottle import Bottle, get, post, request,  response, template, redirect, hook, abort
import bottle

@get('/')
def mainindex():
    return "Hello World"

def apScheduler():
    print "AFTER SERVER START"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 80), botapp)
    threads = []
    threads.append(spawn(server.serve_forever))
    threads.append(spawn(apScheduler))
    joinall(threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an APScheduler [class](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Look at examples of object use and creation in this same site bacause it's too general to give an especific example to copy.

I don't know if [this](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/#advanced-python-scheduler) helps.

```
class Shed(object):
    def __init__(self): # this to start it
        # instruccions here

    def Newshed(self, data):
        # Call from bottle

    # more methods ...


...

# init
aps = Shed() # this activates Shed.__init__()

...

# in the @router
x = aps.Newshed(data)  # or whatever
```

Anyway I'm still learning this stuff and it's just an idea.

Comment: Actually it is a python script which would not disqualify your aproach but that script interacts with the bottle app itself. The thing is the functions that i need to schedule are also part of the bottle app so I can't run the sheduler isolated from that app.

Comment: Create a class that you initialize when you start and then use at need.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but this doesn't help me at all. I'm familiar with all that class and init stuff but what I still need to know is how to call anything (wether initiating something or just calling a function) AFTER the bottle run method without putting it into a routed function. It has to be in this order because the functions that i wan't to shedule are not defined before the server is started (don't know why that is actually)

Answer (score -2):

```
import threading
import bottle

def init_app():
    def my_function_on_startup():
        # some code here
        pass
    app = bottle.app()
    t = threading.Thread(target=my_function_on_startup)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return app


app = init_app()

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "App is running"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle.run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all. It creates a thread, starts it which which will run "some code here" eventually. Then it sarts the bottle server with no connection to the prior.