# Start function on run with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app

```
@app.route("/hello")
def generater():
     return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My application runs fine, but i would like to know how I could make a request to http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello when I compile my code

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"?

Comment: When i execute the command python hello.py the first thing that would happen is that it would go to localhost:port/hello and it would return hello world without me having to go to a webpage and type localhost/hello

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html) to automatically open `http://localhost:5000` in a web browser when running your flask app:

```
import webbrowser
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:5000')
    app.run()
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for just need to try it on the server now! thank you

Comment: This opens a browser, but if you dont want to keep it open? Just wget?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways you could do this. You could just open up your browser to that location. You could try @jimtodd's answer and then cURL the endpoint from another terminal window.

To do it in the code, which I guess is what you want, Flask offers you some helper methods. For example there is: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request

You can use it like this:

```
def foo():
    pass

app.before_first_request(foo)
```

In the case where you want to run a script strictly on run, not just before the first request, this solution is good: [Run code after flask application has started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465533/run-code-after-flask-application-has-started?noredirect=1&lq=1) -- I guess you would use this for cold-start problems as well.

Comment: I dont want this to happen before I make a request, when I run python hello.py i want it to run foo without having to open a browser and make a request

Comment: Edited my response to address this

Comment: It is not effectively a right answer..This performs right before 1st request. Not after start. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this from command prompt:

```
set FLASK_APP=hello.py
python -m flask run
```

The you will see....
    Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

Now you can check the output in your browser.