# How to run a callback after a flask server is up and running?

Tags: python, flask

I need to print "Server is running..." after flask server is started with `app.run()`.
I'm using flask version 1.1.2

I tried using before_first_request decorator, but it doesn't run until first request is sent. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need to perform something like that?

Comment: X Y question, could you please provide more context and share your code?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465533/run-code-after-flask-application-has-started

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I honestly don't know what's so hard to understand about this or why there isn't a hook built-in. If the server isn't ready to accept requests yet, you might want to send a notification when it is ready to accept requests. The answers in that other SO link are all still kind of hacky and some aren't supported anymore